# Adding a scroll bar to a canvas

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to add a scroll bar to my canvas using tkinter but the code i am running is not creating a usable scroll bar. What is the error?

This is the code:

```
proofscreen.title("Proof")
proofscreen.geometry("800x800")
proofscreen.configure(background="white")

# add scrollbar
frame = Frame(proofscreen)
frame.grid()
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="white")
vbar = Scrollbar(frame)
vbar.grid(row=0, column=1)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.update()
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
proofscreen.grid_columnconfigure((0), weight=1)
frame.grid_rowconfigure((0), weight=1)
proofscreen.grid_rowconfigure((0), weight=1)

Label(canvas, text="Proof", font=("Calibri", 16), bg="white", fg="black").pack(anchor=W)
Label(canvas, text="", bg="white", fg="black").pack(anchor=W)
Label(canvas, text="Deduction", font=("Calibri", 14), bg="white", fg="black").pack(anchor=W)
```

I just need the scroll bar to be able to scroll vertically while there are many labels in the canvas

Answer (score 1):

The canvas can only scroll items added with the `create_window` method. It won't scroll items added via `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.